# Hide row based on cell containing text

Tags: vba

Im trying to hide rows based on cells in column B containing "MR0..." and leaving the rows that don't contain "MR0...". Eg, i have a list and want to hide the rows containing over 1000 MR... codes.
MR01010
MR01020
MR01050
MR01052
MR01059
MR01060
MR01080
MR01081
MR01110

I've tried the following, but seem to get stuck at the .value like "*MR0" Then stage...

```
Sub MonthlyStage2()

beginRow = 13
endRow = 500
chkCol = 2

For rowCnt = beginRow To endRow
    If Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).Value Like "*MR" Then
        Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next rowCnt
End Sub
```

&

```
Sub stage2()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ContainWord As String
Dim LR As Long, i As Long

LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
For i = LR To 2 Step -1
If Range("B" & i).Value Like "*MR0" Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True

Next i

End Sub
```

without much luck.
Any help please?
cheers

Comment: Don't you mean `Like "MR*"`?  (Or, if the codes are within other text such as `"This code is MR01010 and is used for demonstration purposes"`, then `Like "*MR*"`.)

Comment: Ive tried the variations though yes, it should be "MR0*". The whole line If Range("B"&i).value like "MR0*" Then is still highlighted.

Comment: Well, changing `"*MR"` in the first set of code you posted to `"MR*"`, and putting values in column B of `MR01010`, `ABC` and `MR21` successfully hid the two rows containing `MR` for me.  And using `"MR0*"` in the second set of code successfully hid just the line containing `MR01010`.

Comment: Ahh - you are getting an error?  What error are you getting?  What is the value of `i` when you get the error?

Comment: Yes, it hides the 1st few rows, then If Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).Value Like "MR*" Then gets highlighted. when using the 1st code

Comment: What error message do you get?  And what is the value of `i` when you get the error?

Comment: when using the 2nd code, it doesn't work at all... "run time erroe '13'

Comment: A type mismatch probably means you have something in the cell that can't be compared to a string.  What is the value of `i` when you get the error?  That will tell us exactly which cell you should look at.  (My guess is you will have a `#N/A` or `#DIV/0!` in that cell, but it would be good to know what cell is causing it to crash so that we don't have to guess.)

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not exactly sure how to check where the error is occurring. all cells in column B are either numeric empty or Text containing MR01010 or MR01020 etc. i ran some check that says it's text, no formatting, no formula.

Comment: When it crashes, and you end up in the code window with `If Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).Value Like "MR*" Then` highlighted, hover your mouse over the variable `i` somewhere in your code - it should give a "tooltip" showing the value.  If it doesn't, type `?i` into the Immediate Window and press Enter.  Or you can use `View / Locals Window` from the menu and see all the variables you have declared in your code and their current values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st code checks starting with Row 13, and the 2nd code starts from the bottom to end at row 2.

Both works fine using criteria `*MR0*` but may prove to be a bit slow especially for large data.

To make it faster, you think of performing the hide operation at one go at the end. Something like this:

```
Sub MonthlyStage2()
    Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, chkCol As Long, rowCnt As Long, r As Range, tmpR As Range
    beginRow = 13
    endRow = 500
    chkCol = 2
    For rowCnt = beginRow To endRow
        If Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).Value Like "*MR0*" Then
            If r Is Nothing Then
                Set r = Cells(rowCnt, chkCol)
            Else
                Set tmpR = Cells(rowCnt, chkCol)
                Set r = Union(r, tmpR)
            End If
        End If
    Next rowCnt
    r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
Sub stage2()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, ContainWord As String, LR As Long, i As Long, r As Range, tmpR As Range
    LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & i).Value Like "*MR0*" Then
            If r Is Nothing Then
                Set r = Range("B" & i)
            Else
                Set tmpR = Range("B" & i)
                Set r = Union(r, tmpR)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks YowE3K & curious. I found the error with i. There was some formula resulting in an error that the codes didn't like. all working fine now. thanks.